# Brownfield | Stetho | ":com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar"

Tags: java, android, facebook, gradle, react-native

I'm integrating React Native into an Android project and I'm running into this gradle issue.

> ":com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar"

```
Module 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
Module 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar

 FAILED
:uscs_core_mobile:buildInfoGeneratorE3PRODLogsDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uscs_core_mobile:prepareE3PRODLogsDebugDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

note: above is what I see after running with --stacktrace

When I inspect my app I don't actually see `stetho-okhttp:1.2.0` instead I see `stetho:1.4.1`.

Has anyone experienced this or have an ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! You need to exclude stetho from gradle. Check out the [issue comments](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10233)

Add to dependencies:

```
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:+") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.stetho', module:'stetho'
  }
```

Also, Stetho has been removed from the Android Library.
Article on 
[why is was removed and how to start using it again](https://medium.com/@andr3wjack/stetho-with-react-native-87642e5d7131#.nu9xsxlhx)